# Google Sheets Equality operator Test of Sheet Objects == or =?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, comparison

The following code creates two sheet objects, and than makes a comparison.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Values");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Values");

  if (sheet==sheet1){Logger.log("sheet==sheet1")};
  if (sheet=sheet1){Logger.log("sheet=sheet1")};
```

The output is only

```
sheet=sheet1
```

I would expect the `sheet` and `sheet1` to be the same. Apparently they are not. How come?
To make it clear, the question is not how to compare, but why these are not references to the same single object?

Also, is using single equation mark `=` really test equality between these sheets, or actually makes some king of assignment?

Comment: `=` is not a comparator operator, it is an assignment operator

Answer (score -1):

`=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#targetText=The%20basic%20assignment%20operator%20is,the%20following%20definitions%20and%20examples.) , it won't compare the two.

`==` would be handy if you're comparing [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) like strings and numbers ( check the link for more ) ,

but in your case,
`getSheetByName` returns an object, you have two of them, not the same instance, you can use `JSON.stringify` to compare them :

`if (JSON.stringify(sheet) == JSON.stringify(sheet1)){Logger.log("sheet==sheet1")};`

Comment: One can use the sheet name `sheet.getSheetName()`, guess it is even better and shorter, I only wouder how come `sheet,sheet1` are not the reference to the same object. I rephrased the question above.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(sheet)` returns `{}` for any object of Class `Sheet`

Comment: I am assuming you rather mean something like this, but it seems a bit heavy: `JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetValues(1,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(),SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxColumns()))`